# Set color of highcharts renderer path title

Tags: css, svg, highcharts, renderer

I'm using a bubble graph to show 2 data points and draw a horizontal and vertical line. What I would like to do is set the color of the title to the same color as the line. The title behaves like a tooltip for the line.

The line is drawn using the following function:

```
function drawLine(chart, line)
{
    chart.renderer.path([
        "M", line.startX, line.startY,
        "L", line.endX, line.endY
    ])
    .css({
        color: line.color,
        fill: line.color
    })
    .attr({
        "stroke-width": 2,
        stroke: line.color,
        title: line.title || "",
        color: line.color,
        fill: line.color,
        useHTML: true,
        zIndex: 2
    })
    .add();
}
```

I'm not sure what I can do to change the color of the title text. Any suggestions?

See this pen for the code: http://codepen.io/kdbruin/pen/EKNBor

Comment: Title in this case is part of browser/OS and to modify color and style you could use something else - like a custom element showing on mouseover/mouseenter. You could add your custom tooltip using Highcharts renderer.

Comment: I tried several of the "renderer with tooltip" solutions found here but none worked properly as they all assume that the tooltip is for a data point. I also tried using the renderer to add some text on mouseover and remove it again on mouseout but that didn't work either (but I didn't fully investigated why). So any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is it the chart title you want to change the color of?

Comment: @KeesdeBruin It worked for me, so maybe there was something wrong with code you were trying to use a different options. I added demo in the answer.

Comment: @RahulSharma It is not the chart title I want to change the color of, but the "tooltip" that is displayed when you hover the mouse cursor over the horizontal or vertical line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title in this case is part of browser/OS and to modify color and style you could use something else - like a custom element showing on mouseover/mouseenter. You could add your custom `text` using Highcharts `renderer`.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqNOyp

Comment: This works like a charm. This was not like any of the solutions I have found. Thanks!